# Bengali Calender JQuery Datepicker Localization

Tags: jquery, localization, calendar, datepicker

Hi I have been working with Bengali language in a multilingual website, what i am up to is , when the language is set to English I need to show jquery datepicker calender in english, and for Bengali I need to show it in Bengali.

I have used jquery datepicker localization.

I have gone through some tutorial and by the process I accomplished part of it. That is I can show January, February etc. Sat, sun etc in English and Bengali . But while I am in Bengali, the digit remains in English.

So, my question is, is there any way out by which I can also change the digit 0-9 in to bengali digit ?

```
jQuery(function($){
        $.datepicker.regional['bn-BD'] = {"Name":"bn-BD","closeText":"Close","prevText":"Prev","nextText":"Next","currentText":"Today","monthNames":["জানুয়ারী","ফেব্রুয়ারী","মার্চ","এপ্রিল","মে","জুন","জুলাই","আগস্ট","সেপ্টেম্বর","অক্টোবর","নভেম্বর","ডিসেম্বর",""],"monthNamesShort":["জানু.","ফেব্রু.","মার্চ","এপ্রিল","মে","জুন","জুলাই","আগ.","সেপ্টে.","অক্টো.","নভে.","ডিসে.",""],"dayNames":["রবিবার","সোমবার","মঙ্গলবার","বুধবার","বৃহস্পতিবার","শুক্রবার","শনিবার"],"dayNamesShort":["রবি.","সোম.","মঙ্গল.","বুধ.","বৃহস্পতি.","শুক্র.","শনি."],"dayNamesMin":["র","স","ম","ব","ব","শ","শ"],"dateFormat":"dd-mm-yy","firstDay":1,"isRTL":false};
});
```

I use this when I detect Bengali as the default language and set empty when I detect the default that is English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by configuring jquery-ui.js file.

Before the iframe pops up, we need to do some pre processing. It can be done by converting each english digit to bengali digit.

My Solution with sample is available here:

[Jquery-Gregorian-Bengali-Calender](https://code.google.com/p/bengali-jquery-calender/source/browse/#svn/trunk)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If worst comes to worst you could always just manually replace the text, no?

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar tr td a').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('1', '১')); 
    //repeat this for each number
});
```

There's probably an easier way, but I think this should work.

NOTE: You'll have to pick out the calendar's iframe first, get the content, and then run this on the content you find in it.